# Android best practice: Bootstrap MainActivity with token

Tags: java, android

I decided to donate my weekend on Android / Java (still very new for me)

And I can't get my head around the way to 'bootstrap' the application.
What is the best way to let the MainActivity decide the 'first-page', depending on if the user has a (todo: valid) token???

Thanks!

In my MainActivity class I have this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (Globals.hasToken(getApplicationContext())) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenuPage.class));
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginPage.class));
    }
    //finish();
}
```

I let the MainActivity decide which page to open next, depending for if the user has a token stored.. Is that good practise?

It shows a 'blank' screen on load for a very short time, before it jumps to Login / MainMenu, specially visible on a slow phone.. And I do not think thats the way it should be

Another option is to load Fragments in MainActivity. But because the Login page also has a Registration page/fragment.. It will become to much 'depth' I think?

Thanks!

Comment: You can either use fragments, or you can use two different layouts and let the token response decide which one to inflate.

Answer (score 1):

Try with fragments, instead of creating new activity.

Comment: Haha I just edited the question, indeed Fragments are 'possible'.. But is that the 'best-practise' way? Or just a possibility that 'works'... I am looking for the best-practise in this case.. Thanks @Tomek

Comment: 'best-practise' depends on your application ;) but there's nothing special in layout that has 2 or more fragments, it's common practise.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Abstract activity for extends other activity with overriding checkTokenMessage(){//here your logic for token checking};
Or u can use singleton Application.class for handling token status in onCreate method of your activities